# List files needed to be repaired by MSI "Repair" (msiexec)

Tags: windows-installer

I know that there are different ways of repair an installation, using either UI (Control Panel) or CLI (msiexec.exe) but:

How do I ONLY list the actions that would have been executed without really repairing. I.e. show "File xyz is missing." or "File abc is modified since install" without restoring them. (The files are installed as Vital and KeyFile).

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Windows Installer.

Comment: The alternative is to unpack the .msi to a temporary folder and diff it manually, pretty ugly.. Just thought that someone else probably have had the same needs.. :/

Comment: That would only work assuming REINSTALLMODE=amus.   You have to take into consideration all of the business rules (file versioning rules) Windows Installer is applying during the costing process.  This is why Rob's answer involves evaluating Component states.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Installer does not expose information about it's operations at that level of granularity. You could write an External UI handler that started the repair operation (call `::MsiConfigureProduct()` after setting up `::MsiSetExternalUI()`) then evaulate the Component states after `InstallValidate` action was called. That should be able to get you the same information that is written to the log file for the Component action states.

Comment: Would he really need an external UI?  I wonder if he could just write a custom action scheduled after InstallValidate to create a list of operations based on component states and sql queries and then show that in a dialog prior to ReadyToInstall?  It would only be there for the Change button of course.   Seems possible, not something that I would likely spend the $$$ to write though.

Comment: A custom action could get the same data but it'd have to get the data out of the custom action (write it to disk somewhere?) and then cancel the install. That seemed more awkward to me than using the external UI handler.

Comment: I guess his story isn't clear to me.  I don't know if he wants an app in the start menu or if he just wants to be able to inform the user before beginning the transaction.

Comment: I read the "ONLY list the actions that would have been executed without really repairing" part of the question to say an actual repair is not desired, just a list of operations.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question per say, but based on your interests, I would suggest reading:

[Application Resiliency: Unlock the Hidden Features of Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302344.aspx#wi_integration_topic4)

The topic "Challenge #1: Self-Invoked Resiliency" is really interesting. It describes a symbiotic relationship between an application and it's installer.  The MSI API was meant to be used by applications to enhance the health checks and not simply invoked by merely COM activation and the use of Advertised shortcuts.

It's really unfortunate that very, very, very few applications in the last 14 years have bothered to take it to this level.